# Upload image from android to python appengine blobstore

Tags: android, google-app-engine, mime-types

I have struggled for quite some time to upload photo images from android to python appengine
This is what I have tried, in Android:

```
void apachePost()  throws Exception {
    File image = new File("/sdcard/image.jpg");
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://clockinapple.appspot.com/upload");
    try {
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
    entity.addPart("type", new StringBody("photo"));
    entity.addPart("data", new FileBody(image));
    httppost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    Log.v(Constants.DATA, "received http response " + response);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e){
  }
}
```

In appengine:

```
class UserPhoto(db.Model):
    user = db.StringProperty()
    blob_key = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload = self.get_uploads()[0]
        user_photo = UserPhoto(user="test", blob_key=upload.key())
        db.put(user_photo)
        return user_photo.key()
```

My logged server error is "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)"

I assume the headers are incorrect - I have tried many variations

Some of the links are have tried:
[Ika Lan's snippet](http://pastie.org/1522810)

[tacticalnuclearstrike blog](http://blog.tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2010/01/using-multipartentity-in-android-applications/)

I would really appreciate any help, I don't seem to be asking the right questions atm

Comment: you need to get the upload url by calling blobstore.get_upload_url('/upload_handler'). I don't see you doing that.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, the image is uploading, I still get this error though "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)" Should I worry about it or ignore it? Regards

Comment: I don't even know what that error means :) where do you see it? On the client side or in the app logs?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have that works (Changed to a HttpGet), the Android code:

```
void apachePost(String url, String filename)  throws Exception {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

HttpResponse urlResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

String result = EntityUtils.toString(urlResponse.getEntity());

Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(filename); // Gets the Uri of the file in the sdcard
File file = new File(new URI(fileUri.toString())); // Extracts the file from the Uri

FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, "multipart/form-data");
StringBody stringBody = new StringBody("Arghhh");

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entity.addPart("file", fileBody);
entity.addPart("string", stringBody);

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(result);

httpPost.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
response.getStatusLine();
    Log.v(Constants.DATA, "received http response " + response);
    Log.v(Constants.DATA, "received http entity " + entity);
}
```

The Appengine Code:

```
class GetBlobstoreUrl(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload/')
    logging.debug(upload_url)
        self.response.out.write(upload_url)

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
        text_files = self.get_uploads('string')
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        user_info = "text_files"
        photo = clockin.UserPhoto(blob_key=blob_info.key(), user=user_info)
        photo.put()
```

One thing that eludes me is what happened to the "entity.addPart("string", stringBody);"
it doesnt seem part of get_uploads in the blobstore object